# Stackelementreference exception in if (Citi.equals("MAA"))

Tags: selenium

I tried to automate the MakeMyTrip site ,I am getting a stale element reference error in line number 42 which i have highlighted .. I have tried all possible solutions..could u please help me with it ..

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Iterator;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice.Return;

public class Dropdown {

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\arthi\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);

    driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");


    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    WebElement Fromcity = driver.findElement(By.id("fromCity"));

    act.doubleClick(Fromcity).perform();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='From']"));

    act.doubleClick(From).perform();


    From.sendKeys("chenn");
```

//List Fromcities=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='react-autowhatever-1']/div[1]/ul/li/div/div[1]/p"));

```
    List<WebElement> Fromcities = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//li/div[1]/div[2]"));

    for (WebElement Cities : Fromcities)

    {

        String Citi = Cities.getText();

        **if (Citi.equals("MAA"))** {

            try {

                Cities.click();

            } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex) {

                Fromcities = driver

                        .findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='react-autowhatever-1']/div[1]/ul/li/div/div[1]/p"));

                Cities.click();

            }

        }

    }
```

//**********to path*******

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='To']")).click();

    WebElement ToPlace = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='To']"));

    act.doubleClick(ToPlace).perform();

    ToPlace.sendKeys("mum");

    List<WebElement> ToCities = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//li/div[1]/div[2]"));

    for (WebElement To : ToCities)

    {

        if (To.getText().contains("BOM")) {

            try {

                JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

                executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", To);

            } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {

                ToCities = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//li/div[1]/div[2]"));

                To.click();

            }

            List<WebElement> Radiobutton = driver

                    .findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='specialFareNew']/li/div[2]/p"));

            for (WebElement Radio : Radiobutton) {

                if (Radio.getText().contains("Armed Forces Fares")) {

                    Radio.click();

                    System.out.println("got the expected output");

                    break;

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Which line is _...line number 42..._?

Comment: once you click it seems like the whole array of webelement references is going stale.  (you sort of tried to work around it, but you're just clicking the stale element again...)  If that click updates the DOM you need to change your approach.

Comment: if (Citi.equals("MAA")) im getting the error in this line

Comment: Hi @pcalkins any idea how to do it ..im just a beginner so finding it difficult

Comment: depending on how the site works and your requirements you might instead get the "href" attributes for the links.  Store those in an array and then iterate using .get(href) during your iteration.